# Which is the Page Replacement Algorithm on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files

I have a huge file that I memory map. This file is larger than the physical memory. Some pages in the file contain index information, they are accessed much more frequently than pages that contain data. I have a program written in c# that I run on Windows 8 to process this file. This program produces lots of hard page faults per second (about 3000 per second).

Index data is about 2Mb. File size 16 Gb. Physical memory 8Gb. Every time I want to locate a data record in the file I need to go through the index.

Accessing index information (frequently accessed pages) does produce the same number of hard page faults than accessing record data (rarely accessed pages)?

**Which is the Page Replacement Algorithm used on Windows?**

EDIT:
I found these pages:

- [Principles of virtual memory](http://www.toves.org/books/vm/). It explains you three page replacement algorithms: FIFO, LRU and CLOCK.
- [Operating Systems (Virtual Memory)](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/9_VirtualMemory.html). On the point `9.10.1 Windows` it says:

> The algorithm for selecting victim frames depends on the type of
>   processor:
>
> On single processor 80x86 systems, a variation of the clock
>   ( second chance ) algorithm is used.
>
> On Alpha and multiprocessor
>   systems, clearing the reference bits may require invalidating entries
>   in the TLB on other processors, which is an expensive operation. In
>   this case Windows uses a variation of FIFO.

So on multicore processors a variation of FIFO is used on Windows which is very unfortunate as the page access frequency is not the factor to take into account.

EDIT:

I'm trying to implement a fast disk hash table. I'm benchmaching it and comparing it with SQLite `(Synchronous=Off;Journal Mode=Off;Page Size=8192)`. I'm inserting key values pairs, keys are 16 bytes long, values are 100 bytes long.

This is what I get for now:

```
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|               |          HugeHashMap         |           SQLite              |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Insertions    | time (ms)    | insertions/ms | ms            | ins/ms        |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  100,000      |  89          |  1,123.6      |  813          |  123.0        |
|  1,000,000    |  1,518       |  658.8        |  11,642       |  85.9         |
|  10,000,000   |  15,819      |  632.2        |  321,807      |  31.1         |
|  100,000,000  |  15,001,549  |  6.7          | 18,604,573    |  5.4          |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: That's very unlikely, pages are only unmapped when they haven't been accessed in a while.  The file data will always generate a hard page fault on first use, one for each 4096 bytes, the most obvious candidate.  Can't be avoided of course.   Using an MMF to sequentially read a file is always a mistake, you can't do better than the file system cache.

Comment: @Hans Passant. I random access the file. I guess pages are also unmapped if there is not enough physical memory to map the requested page. So the quesion is whether the OS would unmap less frequently accessed pages first.

Comment: Sounds like you're always going to have a [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) state based on the MMF being larger than physical memory, but still constantly in use.  You may want to reconsider your program's design at this point to reduce the MMF or use another method for IPC.  I don't quite know what you're attempting to do, but maybe you should memory map the indexes only, and use a slower method or actual database for the record storage.

Comment: If the index information should not be paged out, why not lock those pages to tell the os that you need them to stay live?

Comment: @theB. Exactly, the index information should not be paged out. But how could you tell whether it is being paged out or not? I don't know it without knowing the Page Replacement Algorithm. Regarging locking those pages, it requieres a special permision "Lock Pages in Memory".

Comment: @JNYRanger. Exactly, I'm always on thrashing state. I'm not IPC'ing, just processing a file (writing and reading). What I need is to know if index info is being paged out or not. If it is being paged out, I would consider another approach. By the way. I'm trying to implement an effient disk backed hash table.

Comment: I believe that the replacement algorithm won't really matter since you're using C#, which is running on .NET.  Unless you're using a low-level language like C/C++ it's kind of irrelevant.  (Someone correct me if I'm wrong here).  Are you using managed or unmanaged (unsafe) code for this?  As what @theB said you need to keep the index in memory (not necessarily a MMF) and then access the record from disk or a cache of some sort.  Unless you're trying to create this whole structure as some sort of in-memory only key/value map.  In that case, buy more RAM =)

Comment: @JNYRanger. I believe replacement alghrithm does matters because it determines how many hard page faults are required for inserting a key value pair. In my case, to insert a key value pair I need to access 4 different pages. 6.7 insertions per millisecond and 3000 page faults per second means that there is roughly 0.5 page faults per insertion, which sounds good, but it's not enough for me, I think I can do better. And yes, I'm using unsafe code. My goal is having a fast hash table that doesn't fit in memory, otherwise I would use System.Dictionary